# How to align a button right in Materialize card-action

Tags: materialize

I am using Materialize, and I need to align a button to the right side of the card in the card-action.

This is the code:

```
<div class="card-action">
  <a href="#" class="right">This is a link</a>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

If I remove the `class="right"` then I get this result:

[image]

I want the result from the second image, except the button should be aligned to the right. Am I missing something about the materialize card-action? How should I get this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `right-align` instead of `right` and you've to use it on `card-action` div. You can check about the alignment classes in [Helper](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) page of the documentation.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I
                    require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action right-align">
                <a class="btn blue" href="#">Right</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Card Image]

Answer (score 2):

You Just Need to Mention the Alignement in below way

```
<div class="card-action right-align">
   YOUR CONTENT WILL ALIGHT TO RIGHT
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different, let alone better, than Germa Vinsmoke's answer?